# Is there a router for "personal wireless" space at my office connected to a hardline?

Tags: networking, wireless-bridge

I have a wireless system; however, in my office the signal is week. The internet company will hardwire a connection but I am using my iPad thus needing the wireless.  I understand there is a device (router) that will allow short range wireless for this purpose.  What is the device?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you're after some sort of wireless point which has only a very short range, presumably to prevent others accessing it. While that is certainly possible it's a really poor way to go about it and would result in extremely low throughput. A far better, and certainly more normal, method would be to use a regular wireless point and simply configure it with appropriate security.

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need more detail here - is this **your** office (I.e., are you in charge of the IT systems), and do you mean you have some kind of wireless internet provider? And what exactly is being hard wired in?

If this is some kind of very small office (I.e., just you and one or two others) then any off the shelf wireless router will work. They're typically plug and play.

However, it does depend on what sort of internet connection the company are putting in. If it's standard cable, and they're providing a modem with an Ethernet port then you'll be fine. If it's ADSL then you may need something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

The device is a wireless router. They're available at pretty much every office supply and electronics store.